# Android/IOS Secret expiration management with client credentials flow

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, app-secret

I'd like to know if there is any strategy for managing secret expiration in mobile devices.

In a scenario where an authorization server allows a mobile client to authorize against him using a resource owner password flow in combination with client credentials, with the client secrets having an expiration time.

I've seen there are ways to safely store secrets on Android apps at least, but, how do you manage the secret expiration without publishing a new version of the app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how we have done in our App following [OAuth Refresh Token Standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5).

Step 1: Your API should be sending a standard Auth Token Response as stated [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4)

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

Step 2: Save that response in Shared Preferences/Local Cache/Local Database, we used Shared Preferences (assuming `accountToken` is Object of class created from Response of Auth Token)

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getContext().getSharedPreferences("AUTH_PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY", accountToken.getAccess_token());
editor.putString("AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY", accountToken.getRefresh_token());
editor.putLong("AUTH_EXPIRES_IN_KEY", accountToken.getExpires_in());
editor.putLong("AUTH_TIME_SAVED_KEY", ((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)));
editor.commit();
```

Step 3: Each time you have to use saved Access Token, make sure it is not expired

```
public boolean needsTokenRefresh(String accessToken) {
    if (accessToken == null || accessToken.length() == 0) {
        // no access token to refresh. Don't refresh.
        return false;
    }

    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("AUTH_PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String refreshToken = pref.getString("AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY", null);
    if (refreshToken == null || refreshToken.length() == 0) {
        // no refresh token. Can't refresh.
        return false;
    }

    Integer timeSaved = pref.getInt("AUTH_TIME_SAVED_KEY", 0);
    if (timeSaved == 0) {
        // No recording of having saved the token. Don't refresh.
        return false;
    }

    long expiresIn = pref.getLong("AUTH_EXPIRES_IN_KEY", 0);
    int now = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    int timePassed = Math.abs(now - timeSaved);
    boolean expired = false;
    if (expiresIn <= timePassed) {
        expired = true;
    }
    return expired;
}
```

If `needsTokenRefresh()` returns `false` then use the saved Auth Token. If it returns `true` then go to next step.

Step 4: Make Auth call again with `grant_type` set as `refresh_token` as [stated in standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6)

Step 5: Auth call should return Standard Auth Response as described in Step 1 with token refreshed and new `refresh_token`

Comment: I think you forgot to write down the call that saves the `"AUTH_TIME_SAVED_KEY"` you rely on when determining whether the token is expired or not, so I took the liberty to add it for you. :) In general you should perhaps be a little conservative with this timestamp, as delay (common in mobile) may lead to the server not accepting it although your method says it's not expired (you only check locally). That's an extreme edge case, though and can be handled.

Comment: I think I missed that while truncating extra bits. Thanks for adding.

Comment: This solution has saved me in more ways than one. Thank you! Pretty straight-forward and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

the only way i can think of is when you run the app for the first time it connect to a server and send the phone fingerPrint, the server will send a file only if the fingerPrint is not listed in its database, The file contain current date and a digital signature for this date so the user wont change its value.
and every time you run the app you check the date and the integrity of the date by applying a VerifySignature Method.